# Create a virtual machine in windows azure programmatically with C# code or .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud

As we know that a new feature called  virtual machine has been added in windows azure portal. but i want to create a virtual machine in windows azure programmatically with C# or . net. so can any one please help in this... which API shoud i use or yet the API for .net need to be published by azure people? please any one guide me to do this task.

Answer (score 6):

You'll likely want to use Azure's REST Service Management APIs.  For example, APIs for creating and managing VMs are here:  [Create Virtual Machine Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/jj157194).

The overall API is [documented here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/ee460799)

Since you're in .NET it seems like there would be service management APIs [in the managed SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn578292.aspx), but I didn't see any service management API references there.

Comment: i cheked those links but it consists of some xmls coding.... i tried with windows azure powershell.. i m able to create a virtual machine in azure with powershell commands but i want to invoke those commands in c# code to create a vm and power on and power off. can u help in that? here is the link for windows azure power shell:http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/automating-windows-azure-virtual-machines-with-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add something after the above answers, certainly you can create the Virtual Machines using Power Shell or C# and here is an example I found it might be interesting using the .Net API

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-to-program-control-838bd90b

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is only a [REST API for creating Virtual Machines](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/)

This post shows an example of how to call the [REST API in C# for creating a VM](http://dotnetankit.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/create-persistent-vm-using-windows.html).
Remember that a Virtual Machine and a VMRole are different.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not having seen this question earlier. The [Microsoft Azure Management Libraries](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/) (MAML, for short) can provide this sort of .NET-based access to the Microsoft Azure management APIs. MAML is available as a series of NuGet packages, which were released officially just this week.

To accompany the release I've put out a [blog post](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/announcing-the-general-availability-of-the-microsoft-azure-management-libraries-for-net) linking to a [VS Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07c3e25f-970f-4bce-ba62-28b6e876188c) I wrote for the //build/ conference. This extension provides a walk-thru via VS Project & Item templates, along with some code snippets, that do exactly what you're after - create a VM in Microsoft Azure from a Console Application.

I've written a [few other posts on MAML](http://www.bradygaster.com/category/Windows%20Azure) that offer other pieces of guidance and information. Hope this helps!